# JLabel not Centering

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

So I have been working on a java program an i am trying to get the JLabel centered in the middle of the window, but what ever I do the label is only at the top center. I am hoping someone can help find a way to get the text centered in the middle of the window. Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Lottery extends JPanel implements ActionListener {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5815877011755522230L;

    private JLabel label;

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        make();

    }

    public Lottery() {

        label = new JLabel("Hello There");
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER); 
        add(label);

    }

    public static void make(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Lottery");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Lottery hi = new Lottery();
        frame.setContentPane(hi);

        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }


}
```

Can someone please help me solve this issue.

Comment: You could change the vertical/horizontal alignment of the label or try using a GridBagLayout instead of a BorderLayout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace add(label); with:

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

and don't forget to import java.awt.BorderLayout;

Your code aligns text within the label, but label itself is not centered in your panel. And you'll have to tinker around layouts anyway.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class Lottery extends JPanel {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5815877011755522230L;

    private JLabel label;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        make();

    }

    public Lottery() {

        label = new JLabel("Hello There");
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        //add(label);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }

    public static void make(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Lottery");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Lottery hi = new Lottery();
        frame.setContentPane(hi);

        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }


}
```

Screenshot: https://postimg.org/image/67vjv79jh/

Comment: thanks, but the text is still not perfectly centered, so can you tell me how i can use something like dimensions to fine tune the alignment?

Comment: Well I've tested it before posting and it looks pretty much centered for me (added a screenshot in previous answer), but I did not verify it with a ruler and didn't count pixels, so I believe it might not be perfect :) However, my suggestion would be to use MigLayout. This tool is pretty complex but powerful and flexible. You'll have to learn how to use it, but the results are worth the effort. It is licensed under BSD license, which allows you to use it even in commercial proprietary projects.